# how to do bulk insertion in corda with an example peoject

Tags: corda

Hi everyone i am working on a project in which i need to do bulk insertion transaction like one by one i need to keep making the transaction consider the IOU project in that consider we need to make 10 transaction with bulk insertion then who we will do that can with sample code please

i have read the this https://medium.com/@dinesh.rivankar/corda-can-transaction-batching-benefit-performance-2e9e50b37851
but i am not getting a clear idea of where to make the required changes can anyone help me with code

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you want to create 10 IOU's in one flow call, right? That's easy; you can add as much inputs or outputs to `TransactionBuilder`.
In your case just add 10 outputs to `txBuilder`:

```
IOUState iouState01 = new IOUState(10, me, otherParty, new UniqueIdentifier());
IOUState iouState02 = new IOUState(20, me, otherParty, new UniqueIdentifier());
.
.
IOUState iouState10 = new IOUState(100, me, otherParty, new UniqueIdentifier());

final TransactionBuilder txBuilder = new TransactionBuilder(notary)
                    .addOutputState(iouState01, IOUContract.ID)
                    .addOutputState(iouState02, IOUContract.ID)
                    .
                    .
                    .
                    .
                    .
                    .addOutputState(iouState09, IOUContract.ID)
                    .addOutputState(iouState10, IOUContract.ID)
                    .addCommand(txCommand);
```

Comment: this will create 10 IOU output sate with same iouValue but what i want is 10 IOU transaction with 10 iouValue

Comment: Adnan, the 10 outputs that I added were for 10 different instances; I updated my answer to show you that first you create 10 IOUState instances (with 10 different values), then you add them as outputs. It's straight forward!